# Toolbar isn't displayed in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android

I'm creating a PreferenceFragment which ends up with the toolbar not being displayed and weird style changes.

[image]

I'm using the preference fragment following way:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    }
}
```

This fragment is inside a public class that extends `AppCompatActivity` like other activities in my app. I'm creating `SettingsFragment` in `onCreate` of said activity:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
    .commit();
```

How do I make the toolbar appear and fix this weird style issue?

Edit: I'm targetting API Level 22 and using version 22.2.1 of design support library, and appcompat (v7).

Answer (score 0):

I think , you will have to use `viewpager` for this and in that `viewpager` you can add `fragment`. Or you can add one `toolbar` view in your `fragment` xml like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#693EB4"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:title="Name" />
```

JAVA CODE

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Do you mean create a non-empty activity layout with a toolbar and fragment tag and load fragment inside that tag? 
What about the mishap with style?

Comment: Style is to add action bar theme.